# Socket.IO connect with Params Android

Tags: android, ios, socket.io

We are developing an App on iOS and Android that includes implementation of socket.io for quick messaging.

For iOS we are using Socket Connection with params, where we send the 'user_id' in configuration and the server receives it.

**We are unable to find, the Android implementation of the same scheme.**

Following is the iOS code.

```
// creating dictionary/json to be sent on connection
var dic = NSMutableDictionary()
dic.setValue(["user_id": Profile().getProfile(atr: "_id") as! String], forKey: "connectParams")

// creating socket.io object and passing dictionary into config
socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "http://something.com")!, config: dic as! NSDictionary )
socket!.connect() // works perfectly
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have to do like this. Please try it and let me know is it working for you.

```java
Socket socket = null;

try {
    IO.Options mOptions = new IO.Options();
    mOptions.query = "userId=" + mUserId;
    socket = IO.socket(url, mOptions);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    return Observable.error(e);
}
socket.connect();
```

Comment: what about for multiple params?

Comment: like that : 

```
mOptions.query = "userId=" + mUserId + "&secondparam=" + secondparam;
```